# firebase onChildAdded triggered even when no child is added

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

according to firebase documentation:

onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)
This method is triggered when a new child is added to the location to which this listener was added.

but according to the output that i recieve in Logcat(through my method `logresult()` ) ,i can conclude onChildAdded is triggered even when i am not adding child. and it is triggered foreach child in my node 'captures'

her is my code

```
    private void startMonitoring(){
    paused=false;
    resetgraph();

    now = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    starting = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    starting = starting - starting%3600;

    //logresult(new Date(starting*1000).toString()+" "+new Date((starting+3600)*1000).toString());

    select_part(starting,starting+3600);
    if(listener!=null){
        captures.removeEventListener(listener);
    }

    listener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            long timex = snapshot.child("date_captured").getValue(Long.class);
            starting = timex - (timex % 3600);
            logresult(new Date(starting*1000).toString()+" "+new Date((starting+3600)*1000).toString());

            if ((timex%3600>1)&&(!paused)){
                addentries(timex, snapshot.child("node1").getValue(dataTemplate.class));
            }else if(!paused){
                resetgraph();
                select_part(starting,starting+3600);
            }

            if(paused){
                captures.removeEventListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };

    captures.addChildEventListener(listener);
   }
```

**so what i am missing or doing wrong in my code?**
**also i double checked if i am adding child to my captures node but nothing**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChildAdded` is triggered for each child node when you add the listener, and only then triggered when an additional child is added. So what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Also see the documentation on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events), which says about `onChildAdded`:

> Retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list of items. **This callback is triggered once for each existing child** and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The DataSnapshot passed to the listener contains the the new child's data.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i read the link you provide me and i came across `onChildChanged()` or `onChildMoved()`.so can i use them instead of `onChildAdded()` to solve my issue? since they are not triggered once for each existing child and then again...

Comment: For time travelers, if previousChildName is null, it's a new child, otherwise it already existed.